# Update a table from a join

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `GEMS_PROJECTS`:

```
du_proj_id
du_id
Proj_id
proj_desc
isactive
transuser
trandate
```

A second table `GEMS_DEPARTMENT`:

```
du_proj_id
dept_id
de_dec
isactive
transuser
trandate
```

`du_proj_id` from second table refers to `du_id` from first table and I need update second table `isactive` field.

Note `duid` getting from user to pass first table and second table.

Comment: Why does `du_proj_id` in one table refer to `du_id` in the other table, which also contains a column named `du_proj_id`? This is very confusing. Also if they mean the same thing, why are they different data types?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are trying to set `isactive` in the `department` table to the same value currently in `projects`, for all rows involving the specified `duid`.

```
UPDATE d
  SET isactive = p.isactive
FROM dbo.GEMS_DEPARTMENT AS d
INNER JOIN dbo.GEMS_PROJECTS AS p
ON RTRIM(d.du_proj_id) = p.du_id
WHERE p.du_id = @duid;
```

The most common answer for this problem is [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server/1604212#1604212).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
update GEMS_DEPARTMENT
SET isactive = ???  -- New Value here
from GEMS_PROJECTS
    inner join GEMS_DEPARTMENT on 
        GEMS_PROJECTS.du_id = convert(nvarchar(100), GEMS_DEPARTMENT.du_proj_id)
where GEMS_PROJECTS.du_id = ???  -- filter on duid or any other fields here
```